# How to set Date format as like How many Hours From Now in React native android?

Tags: react-native

My date format is 2021-01-21 10-27-24. and trying to make this Today at 12:57 PM .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install moment --> npm i --save moment

import moment from 'moment

moment('2021-01-28 10-27-24', "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow()